# Howto use fakes Azure.Kudu.kudusync without a manifest

Tags: azure-web-app-service, f#-fake, kudu

When I try to use kudusync with the following command:

```
Azure.Kudu.kuduSync ()
```

I get the following error on Azure:

> Error: The 'nextManifest' option must be specified unless the 'ignoremanifest' option is set.

So I've written my own implementation of kudusync providing an additional parameter `-x` to ignore the manifest and the sync works just fine.

I've seen in the [source code](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/master/src/app/FakeLib/AzureKudu.fs#L12) that there are the following build params defined:

```
/// Used by KuduSync for tracking and diffing deployments.
let nextManifestPath = getBuildParam "NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH"
/// Used by KuduSync for tracking and diffing deployments.
let previousManifestPath = getBuildParam "PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH"
```

so there should be the posibility to add this params, but I haven't seen any usage of these parameters.
The sample project from [Isaac Abraham](https://github.com/isaacabraham/fsharp-demonstrator) doesn't use it either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@TobiasBurger, these parameters can be got from environment variables via the functions [`getBuildParam`](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/41f8e89aa44004eae4337cfed9ade1a6ac2ca33e/src/app/FakeLib/EnvironmentHelper.fs#L104) or [`getBuildParamOrDefault`](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/41f8e89aa44004eae4337cfed9ade1a6ac2ca33e/src/app/FakeLib/EnvironmentHelper.fs#L99) in the source code [`EnvironmentHelper.fs`](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/41f8e89aa44004eae4337cfed9ade1a6ac2ca33e/src/app/FakeLib/EnvironmentHelper.fs).

So you must define the parameter which value returned from `getBuildParam` via command `set PARAMETER_NAME=<PARAMETER_VALUE>` in the current CMD window or set the parameter value pair in the `Environment Variables` Window (see the [help](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)) before run the F# program. And the function `getBuildParamOrDefault` call will return the default parameter value.